# An alternative word to 'Delegate'

Tags: synonyms

Context:

I'm programming a system for exams, each exam has people on it, in the industry we would call one of these people a `'Delegate'`. Unfortunately in the programming language c# `'Delegate'` is a reserved word and I can't really use it without my code looking terrible.

I need a word to represent a person who will be on an exam.

A colleague suggested `ExamSitter` but I think that might have been tongue-in-cheek

Comment: What does "on an exam" mean? One who takes the exam? One who is literally sitting on the exam paper? One whose appellation appears within an exam question? One who has been involved in creating the exam? One who is a proctor or watching the exam takers? One who is a part of a sample for an exam?

Comment: A person taking the exam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could call these people 'candidates'. I don't think candidate is reserved, I've certainly never came across it in C#.

Comment: I agree. Take a look at [this list](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/thesaurus-category/american/general-words-for-exams-and-taking-exams) (Please feel free to add this link or any other documentation on why you think your entry is valid.)

Comment: Indeed, I would not expect a person taking an exam to be called a _delegate_ at all.

Comment: @ColinFine I agree with you, however usually a 'delegate' goes on a course and at the end of the course they sit an exam. I think this word has sneaked into the industry as things have moved on.